# ApiController routing seems to ignore action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, routes

With routing like this defined in RouteConfig.cs

```
  routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Durandal", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

I expected `http://localhost:50441/api/Induction/GetIntro/4108` to parse as

```
Controller = InductionController
Action = "GetIntro"
Id = 4108
```

and call into the GetIntro method of this class

```
using System.Web.Http;

namespace MyMvcApp.Controllers
{
  public class InductionController : ApiController
  {    
    public object GetIntro(int inductionId)
    {     
      //simplified for brevity    
      return new {
        Title = "foo",
        Text = "Some introductory blather"
      };
    }
  }
}
```

But it doesn't. I get a 404 Not Found, and the burning question is why.

Most samples seem to use MapHttpRoute instead of MapRoute, MapRoute being an extension method that wraps MapHttpRoute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was confused by the existence of `RouteConfig.cs` which also defines routes. It works like this:

- WebApi routes are configured by `WebApiConfig.cs`
- MVC routes are configured by `RouteConfig.cs`
- You get both because it's an MVC project with support for WebApi.

In my project the route defined in WebApiConfig.cs was `api\{controller}\{id}` and preceding this with another route `api\{controller}\{action}\{id}` resolved the problem.

The template generated CRUD methods worked because they match `api\{controller}\{id}`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying url `http://localhost:50441/api/Induction/GetIntro/4108`

but you missed to add 'api' to your route definition

Change your route to this

```
 routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Durandal", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: It is my understanding that the extension method MapRoute supplies the "api" part. Also, it was working for the default controller methods. But I tried your suggestion anyway, because if I knew everything about this I wouldn't be asking the question. Alas, it's not a missing prefix.